# Unicode Decoding error when trying to generate pdf with non-ascii characters

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I am working with some software that is generating an error when trying to create a pdf from html that contains non-ascii characters.  I have created a much simpler program to reproduce the problem and help me understand what is going on.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding=utf8
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import pdfkit
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
f = open('test.html','r')
html = f.read()
print html
pdfkit.from_string(html, 'gen.pdf')
f.close()
```

Running this program results in:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>ر</h1>
</body>
</html>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testerror.py", line 10, in <module>
    pdfkit.from_string(html, 'gen.pdf')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfkit/api.py", line 72, in from_string
    return r.to_pdf(output_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfkit/pdfkit.py", line 136, in to_pdf
    input = self.source.to_s().encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried adding a replace statement to strip the problem character, but that also resulted in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testerror.py", line 9, in <module>
    html = html.replace('ر','-')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am afraid I don't understand ascii / utf-8 encoding very well.  If anyone could help me understand what is going on here, that would be great!  I am not sure if this is a problem in the pdf library, or if this is a result of my ignorance of encodings :)

Comment: "I am afraid I don't understand ascii / utf-8 encoding very well" => Read this first then : http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I have read it. However, i would still appreciate some help with this particular situation.

Comment: what encoding is your test.html file in ? Obviously pdfkit expects a Unicode string so it's your duty to decode it before you pass it to pdfkit....

Comment: [Read `import codecs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#module-codecs). Then, `f = codecs.open('test.html','r','utf-8')` could help as byte sequence `0xD8`, `0xB1` is utf-8 one for  _Arabic Letter Reh_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading `pdfkit` source code, it appears that `pdfkit.from_string` expects its first argument to be `unicode` not `str`, so it's up to you to properly decode `html`. To do so you must know what encoding your `test.html` file is. Once you know that you just have to proceed:

```
with open('test.html') as f:
    html = f.read().decode('<your-encoding-name-here>)
pdfkit.from_string(html, 'gen.pdf')
```

Note that `str.decode(<encoding>)` will return a `unicode` string and `unicode.encode(<encoding>)` will return a byte string, IOW you `decode` from byte string to unicode and you `encode` from unicode to byte string.

In your case can also use `codecs.open(path, mode, encoding)` instead of `file.open()` + explicit decoding, ie:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('test.html', encoding=<your-encoding-name-here>) as f:
    html = f.read() # `codecs` while do the decoding behind the scene
```

As a side note:

- read (read binary for `codecs` but that's an implementation detail) is the default mode when opening a file so no need to specify it all
- using files as context managers (`with open(path) as f: ...`) makes sure the file will be properly closed. While CPython will usually close opened filed when the `file` objects get collected, this is an implementation detail and is **not** garanteed by the language, so do not rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Also HTML should include charset

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be Python 2 specific. However, I had a similar issue with Python 3 in a Flask + Apache/mod_wsgi environment on Ubuntu 22.04. when passing a non-ASCII-string to the header or footer via the `from_string` options (e.g. `document = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, options={"header-left": "é"}`). I then got the error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`. The problem was the missing `locale` setting for `WSGIDaemonProcess` in the Apache/VirtualHost configuration. I solved it by passing `locake=C.UTF-8`: `WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=myuser group=mygroup threads=5 locale=C.UTF-8 python-home=/path/to/myapp/venv`.